# "Отрезать хлеб" или "отрезать хлеба"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно говорить: "отрезать хлеб" или "отрезать хлеба"?

Answer (score 1):

Отрезать хлеба.
"Отрезать" - это в отношении части чего-то, а часть обычно передаётся родительным падежом. Вот взять, положить, купить и т.д. можно и хлеб, и хлеба -  с несколько разными значениями.

Подумалась. Ведь и вариант "отрезать хлеб" не слишком жизненный, но не фантастичный. Хлеб застрял, приварился, прилип и проч. Тогда можно и "отрезать хлеб" с целью избавиться от него. После обеда в бороде у батюшки крошки застряли. А матушка ему ножницы несет: "Отрежь, мол, хлеб". (Прям по Ильфу-Петрову получается).

Answer (score 0):

1) хлеба - часть от целого
2) вариант "хлеб" - не сыр, не колбасу, объектное значение

Comment: А как можно **отрезать** не часть? В нормальном контектсе, разумеется. Я думаю, что логично будет "отрежь хлеба, не колбасы, не сыру", т.е. все равно родительный.